XFCE: M-Tab, active windows and „Always on Top“
I run XFCE under X11 with focus policy „focus follows mouse“.  What happens when I open an application, create a new (second) window in it, set it to „Always on Top“ from window menu, move the mouse  pointer into it, and press M-Tab (aka Alt-Tab)?  It has turned out in my experiments that different applications behave differently in this respect.  For Okular, Thunar and Firefox, pressing M-Tab results in the first window becoming active; for XFCE Terminal and Emacs, the second window remains active as long as the mouse pointer is in it, and there seems to be no way to make the first window active using the keyboard.  What does this behavior depend on?  How could I make Emacs behave like Okular so that I don't have to reach for the mouse to make the non-always-on-top window active?
My version of XFCE is 4.18.

I may have an idea.  I wrote this shell program that will toggle a window on/off always on top mode.  It has a keybinding option.
I modified it to use two windows.  You select both of them when you run it, then from there, it will switch the always on top between the two selected windows.  Make sure the second window will be visible after the first one, because it will go "on top" right then.
Set the keybinding and you can use the keyboard to switch between them via "always on top".
#!/bin/bash

remove_keybind() {
    rm -f ~/.ontop_tray_xkbrc
    xdotool windowkill "$(cat /tmp/xwin_id_xkb 2>/dev/null)"
    set_keybinding
}
export -f remove_keybind

set_keybinding() {
    local current_binding="[none]"

    if [[ -f ~/.ontop_tray_xkbrc ]]; then
        current_binding=$(sed '2q;d' ~/.ontop_tray_xkbrc)
    else
        echo "\"bash -c 'toggle_gnome'\"" > ~/.ontop_tray_xkbrc
    fi

    local show_current=$(echo "$current_binding")
    yad --window-icon="input-keyboard" --borders=15 --on-top --skip-taskbar --title="Key Binding" \
        --text-align="center" --buttons-layout="center" --text="Current Binding\n$show_current\n" \
        --separator=" " --item-separator=" " --print-xid="/tmp/xwin_id_xkb" --form \
        --field="Hold 1:":CBE "Ctrl Alt Shift" \
        --field="Hold 2:":CBE "Shift Ctrl Alt" \
        --field="Action:":entry "T" \
        --field=Remove-Binding:BTN "bash -c 'remove_keybind'" \
        --button=Confirm:0 \
        --button=Cancel:1 > /tmp/entries

    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        exit 1
    fi

    local entries
    entries=$(cut -d'|' -f1 < /tmp/entries)

    local f1 f2 f3
    f1=$(echo "$entries" | awk '{print $1}')
    f2=$(echo "$entries" | awk '{print $2}')
    f3=$(echo "$entries" | awk '{print $3}')

    local key_combo
    key_combo=$(echo "$f1+$f2+$f3" | tr ' ' '+')

    if [[ "$current_binding" == "[none]" ]]; then
        echo "$key_combo" >> ~/.ontop_tray_xkbrc
    fi

    xbindkeys -p --file ~/.ontop_tray_xkbrc
}
export -f set_keybinding

tmp_error() {
    yad --skip-taskbar --on-top --window-icon="gtk-error" --title="Write Error" --image="gtk-error" \
        --button="Quit":1 \
        --text="Unable to write to /tmp\nCheck permissions for $USER."
    exit 1
}
export -f tmp_error

error_control() {
    yad --skip-taskbar --on-top --window-icon="dialog-question" --title="Retry?" --image="dialog-question" \
        --button="Try Again":0 \
        --button="Quit":1 \
        --text="Failed to focus on the window.\nDo you want to retry?"

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        select_windows
    else
        exit 1
    fi
}
export -f error_control

select_windows() {
    for i in 1 2; do
        xdotool selectwindow > "/tmp/xwin_id_$i"

        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            error_control
        fi

        if [ ! -f "/tmp/xwin_id_$i" ]; then
            tmp_error
        fi

        wmctrl -i -r "$(cat /tmp/xwin_id_$i)" -b add,above
    done
}
export -f select_windows

toggle_between_windows() {
    local window1_id
    local window2_id

    window1_id=$(cat /tmp/xwin_id_1)
    window2_id=$(cat /tmp/xwin_id_2)

    xprop -id "$window1_id" | grep -q "_NET_WM_STATE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_STATE_ABOVE"
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        wmctrl -i -r "$window1_id" -b remove,above
        wmctrl -i -r "$window2_id" -b add,above
    else
        wmctrl -i -r "$window1_id" -b add,above
        wmctrl -i -r "$window2_id" -b remove,above
    fi
}
export -f toggle_between_windows

select_windows

yad --notification --skip-taskbar --image="go-top" \
    --command="bash -c 'toggle_between_windows'" \
    --menu=" Re-select !bash -c 'select_windows' \
    | Keybind !bash -c 'set_keybinding' \
    | Exit !bash -c 'wmctrl -i -r $(cat /tmp/xwin_id_1) -b remove,above; wmctrl -i -r $(cat /tmp/xwin_id_2) -b remove,above; killall yad'" \
    --text="Always On Top!"

exit 0

Save as: toggle_on_top.sh
Change mode executable: chmod +x toggle_on_top.sh
Usage: ./toggle_on_top.sh &disown

Unfortunately, this did not answer my question.  I don't want to change the "Always on Top" status of neither of the two windows; I only want to make the non-always-on-top window active.

@toomas Unless you need them simultaneously, it will give it focus for the moment you need it, then toggle the "always on top" back to the usual on top window.  I can also modify it to behave many other ways.
